# Jest - how to test outcome of promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-promise

Using Jest how can I test the steps executed when a promise in the function under unit test is resolved?

Example:

```
// FUNCTION TO TEST
export function functionToTest(url) {
  initSomething().then(() => {
    console.log('YEP, CALLED');
    storeHistory.push(url);
  });
}

// UNIT TEST
import { functionToTest, __RewireAPI__ as rewireUtility } from './funcToTest';

describe('functionToTest', () => {
  let pushSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    pushSpy = jest.fn();
    rewireUtility.__set__('storeHistory', { push: pushSpy });
    rewireUtility.__set__('initSomething', () => Promise.resolve());
  });

  it('pushes the given url to history after initializing cordova', () => {
    functionToTest('/sports');
    expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/sports');
  });
});
```

In this case pushSpy gets called 0 times (even if the log is printed out). How can I correctly test this?

Comment: for one thing, your `functionToTest` isn't returning the promise so there's nothing for `await` to wait on, so it won't.

Comment: Good point, I was trying that route. Same outcome removing it.

Comment: sorry, removing what? ~deleted~ no, my bad

Comment: I'd be inclined to remove the use of rewire myself. You should be able to `jest.mock` initSomething, but that's not likely to resolve anything.

Comment: If I use the following it times out.. `global.history = { push: (route) => {
        expect(route).ToEqual('/sports');
        done();
      }};` (but the console.log is called..)

Comment: Argh, dumb me. It's the store history not `window.history`, it was not mocked out correctly.

Comment: cool, I was trying to work out what the history was.. 8) ..also, rather than remove `await` you need to `return initSomething().then(()...` and make the test function async, ie `describe('functionToTest', async () => {`

Comment: Haven't solved yet even mocking out the right history object. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this:

```
it.only('pushes the given url to history after initializing cordova', (done) => {
  rewireUtility.__Rewire__('history', { push: (route) => {
        expect(route).toEqual('/sports');
        done();
  } });
  functionToTest('test://sports');
});
```